# Unable to create virtual environment in windows using this command

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

Unable to create virtual environment in windows using this command in command prompt

python3 -m venv whatsapp-bot-venv

It throws an error as below

'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 1):

Use

> python -m venv whatsapp-bot-venv